# Kubernetes etcd db size grows continuously and system gets unstable when using --anonymous-auth=false

Tags: kubernetes, configuration, feature-flags

I have a problem with the growing db size of etcd. This causes the entire Cluster to become unstable.
Pods gets evicted and the Kubernetes-API server crashes every now and then.

I identified that this only happens when using the `--anonymous-auth=false` flag in the Kubernetes-API manifest file.

Is there a solution for this except deleting the flag? I would like to have anonymous access blocked.

Comment: if etcd grows, you should look for which objects are being added/updated. You could look into setting up Kubernetes audit logs (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/audit/), digging through api calls (can be painful, forwarding those logs to some EFK, splunk, ... will help). Prometheus + kube-state metrics might help as well (barely). If you think there's a bug in Kubernetes: you might be right, don't hesitate to report this on GitHub: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues

Comment: in doubt, could you edit your question, sharing your `/etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml`? And tell us which version of kubernetes & etcd you are using?